# leafref inside grouping to grouping

Tags: schema, modeling, ietf-netmod-yang

I want to create a `leafref` from one `grouping` to another, is it possible?
I have the following files:

**a.yang**:

```
module a
{
    namespace "http://something.com/a";
    prefix a;

    import b
    {
        prefix b;
    }

    description "a configuration";

    container a
    {
        uses b:group1;
        uses b:group2;
    }
}
```

so, module `a` has two instances, `group1` & `group2`.
I want a `leafref` from `group2` to point on a `leaf` from `group1`.

**b.yang**:

```
module b
{
    namespace "http://something.com/b";
    prefix b;

    description "b configurations";

    grouping group1
    {
        container group1
        {
            leaf parameter-x
            {
                type uint8;
            }
        }
    }

    grouping group2
    {
        container group2
        {
            leaf ref-parameter-x
            {
                type leafref
                {
                    path "????/parameter-x of group1";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understood it, Yang is not normally used for modeling SNMP equipment. Instead it's SMI. Can you explain the presence of the "snmp" and "mib" tags?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with `augment`.
I do not know if possible with `grouping`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in YANG and, if you think about it, with good reason. When you create a `grouping`, you create a hierarchy of reusable non-namespaced data nodes which only start to make sense once the `grouping` is used. You can use those anywhere and they may even be used by someone else who imports your module (provided that groupings are defined at module top-level). By anywhere, I mean at any level within a YANG module. This means that you cannot use absolute nor relative paths to identify a leaf from your grouping:

```
container top {
  uses group1;
  container foo {
    uses group1;
  }
}
```

There are already two paths that could identify your leaf (again assuming top-level):

- `/top/group1/parameter-x`
- `/top/foo/group1/parameter-x`

So which one of these absolute expressions is the correct one to specify in your second `grouping`? If the answer is "either one", you cannot model this. If however you have a specific leaf in mind, you could do this (used a typedef to make it obvious that we are talking about a specific leaf):

```
typedef my-special-leaf {
  type leafref {
    path "/top/foo/group1/parameter-x";
  }
}

grouping group-2 {
  container group-2 {
    leaf special {
      type my-special-leaf;
    }
  }
}
```

`Leafrefs` are used for `leafs` that may get instantiated and you know this for a fact (are part of the schema tree). If you only define the `leaf` inside a `grouping`, it has not yet become a part of the schema tree. Not until used (anywhere but inside another `grouping`).

A good reusable `grouping` definition assumes nothing about the location at which it will be used.